# ssh mysqldump from oscent to remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, mysql, remote-server

I'm trying to create automated backups of the mysql databases from my virtual host to my NAS storage.

I'm only just starting to learn shell commands so please bear with me - what I've found so far is:

```
mysqldump 
   -uusername 
   -ppassword 
   --opt database_name | 
   gzip -c | 
   ssh user@ipaddress 
   "cat > /path-to-the-directory-on-nas/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H.%I.%S).sql.gz"
```

but this seem to return the following error:

> -bash: /path-to-the-directory-on-nas/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H.%I.%S).sql.gz: No such file or directory

Does anyone know how to overcome this problem and actually save it to the designated storage?

Comment: What storage engine do you use? mysqlhotcopy is much faster for MyISAM

Comment: Not quite sure - how would I find this information?

Comment: `SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM your_db;` see `Engine` column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
cat > /path-to-the-directory-on-nas/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H.%I.%S).sql.gz
```

to

```
cat > /path-to-the-directory-on-nas/`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H.%I.%S`.sql.gz
```

Make sure the folder already exists. At least worked on my Ubuntu :)

Comment: Thanks raynix - I'll give it a try again.

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work either. I've checked the directory with pwd and copied it to the command to make sure it's the right path etc. but still - no luck - haven't got a clue what it might be.

Comment: Also make sure you can enter that dir and can write file there.

Comment: The virtual host is with CentOs 6.2 and I'm not 100% what's installed on my Qnap NAS, but I believe it's some Linux flavour.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the directory */path-to-the-directory-on-nas/* exists on the remote server.

If it is missing you can create it over ssh with the following command:

```
 ssh user@ipaddress mkdir -p /path-to-the-directory-on-nas/
```

( using the -p if there is multiple directories tree that need to be created )

If you wanted to create the directory with a time stamp you should do the following:

```
 ssh user@ipaddress mkdir -p /path-to-the-directory-on-nas/$(date '+%Y%M%D')/'
```

If you choose to include a timestamp in the directory path, you need to include it in the path that your mysqldump command uses.

**Example:**

Successfully create the file to a remote directory that exists on the remote system */var/tmp*

```
 $ date | ssh user@ipaddress 'cat > /var/tmp/file.txt'
 $ ssh user@ipaddress cat /var/tmp/file.txt
 Fri Oct 12 19:39:16 EST 2012
```

Failing with the same error you are getting, trying to write to a directory that dosn't exist.

```
 $ date | ssh user@ipaddress 'cat > /var/Xtmp/file.txt'
 bash: /var/Xtmp/file.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Thanks dannyla - could you also explain how I could crate the directory with the current date and time on the remote server please?

Comment: Use the same process as your creating the dump file, however you might need to remove some of the time resolution ( eg. seconds ).

    ssh user@ipaddress mkdir -p /path-to-the-directory-on-nas-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H')/

Answer (score 1):

You should debug further. First try

```
cat > /path-to-the-directory-on-nas/test.sql.gz.
```

After that you should try if the date works:

```
echo $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H.%I.%S)
```

Then you'll know if the path exists or if date... fails. From your error msg it seems like the date is the problem but you need to be sure first. Then you could try to assign the date to a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
 filename=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H.%I.%S);
    mysqldump 
       -uusername 
       -ppassword 
       --opt database_name | 
       gzip -c | 
       ssh user@ipaddress 
     "cat > /path-to-the-directory-on-nas/$filename.sql.gz"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
ssh user@ipaddress 
   "cat > /path-to-the-directory-on-nas/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H.%I.%S).sql.gz"
```

with

```
ssh user@ipaddress 
   "cat > /path-to-the-directory-on-nas/"$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H.%I.%S)".sql.gz"
```

Comment: Thanks YaK - unfortunately it doesn't seem to make any difference.